# Backslash vs forwardslash when moving files in python

Tags: python, operating-system, shutil

To move some files i am using this code:

```
import glob
import os
import shutil

list_of_files = glob.glob('C:/Users/user/staff/*') 
latest_file = max(list_of_files, key=os.path.getctime)
print(latest_file)
filename= os.path.basename(latest_file)

shutil.move(latest_file, f"C:\\Users\\user\\test folder\\{filename}"
```

The code works and the file has moved but i would like to know if this actually matters:

The file which was moved is this:

```
C:/Users/user/staff\Aug-2021.csv
```

Notice the slash is now backward instead of forward. Does the orientation of slash matter or would matter in future when my code becomes more complicated(for best practices) or is this how it is suppose to work?

Comment: Have you considered using a Pan-Galactic Gargle Blaster?

Comment: Well, it is the best drink in existence!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both will work, but mixing slash and backslash is at least ugly. If you want to do something os independent, you can use `os.sep` to get the seperation character of your os.

```
>>> import os
>>> os.sep
'\\'
```

With this you could do something like

```
>>> os.sep.join(['foo','bar'])
'foo\\bar'
```

But you can also use `os.path.join` to build the path and let python handle that problem for you.

```
>>> import os
>>> os.path.join(os.getcwd(),'foo.bar')
'C:\\Users\\Me\\foo.bar'
```

Answer (score 1):

Both foward or backslash are perfectly valid path separators. Also, it is a good practice to include 'r' before a path string:

```py
r'C:\Users\user\staff\Aug-2021.csv'
```

The means your string will be treated as a raw string. You can see string literals reference [here](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals)

Comment: Because it is an f- string how do i include both r and f in front of it?

Comment: You don´t have to use 'f' in this case, just do `"r"C:\Users\user\test folder\{}".format(filename) "`

Answer (score 1):

Both works same but try to use `\` slash to avoid 0.1 chance of error.
And I also get error of encoding so add r before the path eg : `r"C:\\Users\\user\\test folder\\{filename}"` .

Hope that answers the question.

Comment: Because it is an f- string how do i include both r and f in front of it?

Answer (score 0):

**case1:when using backward slash(i.e in the case you copied directly from file path) you can just use the below code:**

import pandas as pd

df=pd.read_csv(r"*filepath\filename.csv*")

note: ensure all slashes are backward slash

**case2:** **when using forward slash you can use the below code:**

import pandas as pd

df=pd.read_csv("*filepath/filename.csv*")

note: ensure to use all forward slash. you can also choose to use r in this case as it would also work perfectly well i.e

df=pd.read_csv(r"filepath/filename.csv")

Comment: It may be helpful to other users to format your code chunks so it is easier to piece apart which parts of this answer are code and which are just you clarifying via text.